# How to get a white background when photoshooting clothing

Tags: lighting, camera-settings, product-photography, background

I am trying to shoot some garments such as hoodie tshirts.

I am using 2 softboxes with white lights of 350W each on a white background. The lighting looks good.

As per camera, I am using my 18-105mm Nikon lens shooting on Aperture mode with 200 ISO and some extra exposure, not zooming too much. I had the aperture at f3.4 or so and did not use a tripod.

However, when checking my photos, the background does not come white at all, it is still very yellow. The garment looks ok. It could be better but my concern is the background. It definitely has to do with the camera settings as the lighting set up is good.

How can I get a good white background so I can avoid too much Photoshop post retouching? What settings in my camera can help me with this?

Comment: What have you searched for(and found) already on this site and what didn't it already answer for you? Please do explain.

Answer (score 0):

Are your garments laying on the white background, or is the background back a few feet?

White backgrounds back a few feet are farther from the light, and so will look gray, and need their own background light to light it to about the same intensity as the foreground.  It is simply the usual practice.  Put enough light on the background to look very white.  Yellow sounds like white balance is not right.  Normally we adjust white balance so white looks white.

Comment: Laying on the floor on a white background. Could you expand on the White Balance?

Comment: If the garment is laying on the white backgrond, then there is no difference in their distance - so exposure of the white should be ok, not reduced to gray.  But if yellow, that is white balance.  I don't know what tools you have, but adjust white balance so that white is white. Some programs have a white balance tool, that we can click something white, and the program will adjust to make it be white.  See http://www.scantips.com/lights/whitebalance.html for more